# How can I lower the memory usage in nautilus elementary?

Tags: nautilus-elementary, memory-usage

Currently Nautilus is using around 175 to 185MB of RAM. This seems unnecessary, since there are no folders open, only dropbox and ubuntu one running (plugins), and no other known sources of this RAM hogging.

What can I do to lower Nautilus memory hogging?

Comment: Does this happen with pure Nautilus (upstream) too?

Comment: Using elementary, I'm only seeing nautilus take up 34megs here. The process has been running for about 2 days, in fairly heavy use. I suggest you might want to disable DropBox and U1 for a day and see what happens.

Comment: @Oli I guess... I have things I keep backing up daily on DropBox, but its worth a try I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was not Dropbox or Ubuntu One after all. I disabled some other plugins: coverthumbnailer, eicel, ground control, etc, and restarted nautilus.

Memory usage dropped to 45MB. Much better!
I will continue to try to see if there are any other culprits, and also if I can narrow down the cause to one or two plugins, but I'm satisfied for now.